# Angular with Web API Bearer authentication keep failing

Tags: jquery, angular, authentication, asp.net-web-api, bearer-token

Working on a new app with Angular 5 and Web Api version is 5.2.3 on dot net framework 4.6.1. The api is just a new Web Api project with individual authentication created on VS2017. The only changes on api is the following line in Startup.Auth.cs with Cors library added to allow cors.

```
app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
```

From Angular app, login and register is working but can't authorize when calling to Web Api including end points such as api/Account/Logout.

keep failing with this error. No cors error.

**Authorization has been denied for this request.**

Angular code.

```
var token = localStorage.getItem("accessToken");
let headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);

this._http.post(environment.authApiUrl + 'api/Account/Logout', { headers: headers}).subscribe(
  data => {
    localStorage.removeItem("userName");
    localStorage.removeItem("accessToken");

    this.isLoggedin = false;        
    this._router.navigate(['/home']);
  },
  errors => console.log(errors)
);
```

I can't think of what was i doing wrong so tried to rewrite in jquery. Works like a charm. No changes in Api at all. what am i doing wrong in Angular?

```
var token = localStorage.getItem("accessToken");
var headers:any = {};
headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + token;
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: environment.authApiUrl + 'api/Account/Logout',
  headers: headers
}).done(function (data) {
    toastr.info(JSON.stringify(data));
}).fail(function (err) {
  toastr.error(JSON.stringify(err));
});
```

Comment: please share details about the error. What are you trying to do, what is working, what exactly is the error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to inspect your headers in your code, you would actually see that they are not being sent. **[Docs](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpHeaders)** state for the description of `HttpHeaders`:

> Immutable set of Http headers.

So the difference from the previous headers (`Http`), you could do:

```
let headers = new Headers();
headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
```

now (`HttpClient`) you need to do:

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders()
  .set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token)
```

or alternatively:

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders()
headers = headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
```

**[because](https://medium.com/spektrakel-blog/angular-httpclient-enforces-immutability-dad161d8714b)**...

> `HttpHeaders` is immutable — all mutation operations return a new instance.

Comment: that was indeed the problem. it works like a charm now. many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I read it again and it says 'no cors error' so ignore the answer below.

## Old Answer

I can't say what the difference between Angular and jQuery way exactly is, I assume one is XHR the other one fetch .. but don't nail me down here.

I had similar issues and when you get a 'No cors' error, this means that the request could actually still work fine BUT your browser tries to protect you here. My strong feeling is that Angular uses a technique where this browser mechanism kicks in and jQuery doesn't.

Long story short:

The issue is that the frontend URL is different from your backend. Your browser doesnt like it and does a preflight request.

Solution:

- Either set up CORS on the backend, or
- use jsonp instead https://angular.io/api/http/Jsonp, or
- work on the same url with both front and backend